# Unity3d transform.position not returning the correct value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

A little background on what I'm working on : Basically I have a cube model which will be used to generate some terrain structure. All of those gameobjects were created on Runtime by doing :

```
float yPos = 0f;
 float scale = 0.5f;
 var robot = GameObject.Instantiate(grassTile) as GameObject;
 robot.transform.position = new Vector3(0, yPos, 0);
 robot.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);
 robot.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0);

 width = robot.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.z;
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
     yPos += width;
     robot = GameObject.Instantiate(grassTile) as GameObject;
     robot.transform.position = new Vector3(0, yPos, 0);
     robot.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);
     robot.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0);
     //attach the script
     robot.AddComponent<CubeBehavior>();
 }
```

What's inside the CubeBehavior.cs :

```
void Start () {
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
         if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
             Debug.Log(transform.position);
         }
 }
```

What happened is no matter which cube I touch, it will always return the last cube position. Please enlighten me about this problems. Thanks in advance

Comment: I noticed you are taking the z (depth) bounds value, call it width and assign it to y (height), it might be justified by that z rotation you make, but just something that popped up. also, for the objects to appear in different places, the would have to have differend bounds.z size - as you reset the ypos to zero at the start

Comment: yeah was bad on my part to use z bounds value and the variable naming(i have changed it). But since it's a cube (width, height and depth are the same size) I don't have any problem in displaying them. What makes it a problem is that it always return the last cube position no matter which cube I touched.

Comment: well, you didn't include the code related to touching - I hope you know Input.touchCount returns the number of SCREEN touch points, not the individual object

Comment: I've included the code above. CubeBehavior.cs is the script I attached to the gameobject

Comment: From the code you provided, It would not matter "which cube you touch". When you touch the screen, all cubes should Log they own position. From your code I would expect 6 logs, and because of the order in which you created the tiles, and hence the order they have in the gameObjects list, I'd expect to have the last position logged also last which might by why you think that that is THE position "returned"? where it really just is ONE of the 6 positions "returned"? Please check that and let us know if you have more clarifications

Comment: @Daveloper Ah yes.. that's exactly what happened. Actually after I'm moving another GameObject ( the character) towards the cube position. That's why my character always move to the last cube. But after I checked the log, it logged out all of the cube's position

Comment: so i assume we still have no clue what your problem is. You're now writing about indeed getting all five logs, but some character moving to the last cube. Never read about characters in your question. Is that what "returns" means? that the character goes there, hence the click returns that cube? can you provide the code that makes the character presumably go to the tile you click on? Maybe we can help you to achieve what you want... just need to help us help you. When you explain a problem, assume your audience has NO context. you can not imply things in your question.

Comment: What does "return" mean in your question? we can see your code and tell you exactly what it does. If it's not doing what you want, you'll need to tell us 1)the code 2)what you want it to do, and 3)how it's not doing what you want it to do. Then we can explain why it's doing what it does and how you can change it to do what you want it to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no code that detect **which** cube was touched.

`Input.touches` just tells you how many touches are currently detected on the screen.

To detect touches, you will need to do some more work. One of the possible solution is to implement touch event handlers. Example inspired from [the doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html):

```
public class CubeBehaviour : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    //Detect current clicks on the GameObject (the one with the script attached)
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        //Output the name of the GameObject that is being clicked
        Debug.Log(name + " click down at position " + transform.position);
    }

    //Detect if clicks are no longer registering
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(name + "No longer being clicked");
    }
}
```

This will need an `EventSystem` somewhere in your scene. Potentially, you will also need trigger colliders on the cubes, not sure

Comment: You don't need colliders but a [`PhysicsRaycaster`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PhysicsRaycaster.html) on the camera in case you want to click on non-UI objects (see [IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html))